# Fire events based on a text file

Tags: java, multithreading, time, observer-pattern, simulator

I have a text file that contains records of events, each with a timestamp. I want to create an engine that simulates the data from the file, in real time. Eventually my project will work with live data, but I am trying to create a testing framework.

In other words:

1. `Simulator` Thread

   - Read file, create event when timestamp occurs
2. `Worker` thread

   - Process data (this is the code will remain when we go to production)
3. Event handoff / `Notifier` thread??? (See below)

I am trying to figure out how best to implement `Simulator`. It seems wrong to me to read one line at a time, and then sleep the number of milliseconds until that event occurs. Some events are less than 10 ms apart. What I'd like to do is have an event queue so that I can get ahead when events are far apart, so that I have minimal processing to do when they are near each other.

Perhaps `Simulator` should really be 2 threads, one that reads the file and puts events in the queue, and one that handles them and fires off events to the work thread (see above, `Notifier` thread). Does that sound reasonable? Below is some code that outlines what I'm thinking. Am I on the right track? Not included here is the thread that reads the file and creates `MyEvent`s.

```
public class Notifier implements Runnable {
    private long firstStartTime;
    private long realStartTime;
    private Worker theWorker;

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if (eventQueue.peek().getTriggerTime() - this.firstStartTime >=
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - this.realStartTime) {
                GlobalQueue.getInstance().offer(eventQueue.poll());
                theWorker.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class GlobalQueue implements Queue<MyEvent> {
    private Queue<MyEvent> myQueue;
    private static GlobalQueue _instance = new GlobalQueue();
    private GlobalQueue() {
        myQueue = new LinkedList<MyEvent>();
    }
    public static getInstance() { return _instance; }
}

public class Worker implements Observer, Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(events.peek() != null) {
                 MyEvent event = GlobalQueue.getInstance().poll();
                 // handle the event
            }
            wait();
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think? Good, or would you make major design changes?

Comment: Did you ever try a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)? I think it would fit fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Timer it's most important to have a TimerTask that is able to fire your event when it comes to it:

```
public class EventFirer extends TimerTask {
    private final MyEvent event;

    public EventFirer(MyEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void run() {
        event.fire();
    }
}
```

Now you only have to put all the EventFirers in a Timer:

```
public Timer fillTimer(List<Date> firingTimes) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    for (Date whenToFire: firingTimes) {
        timer.schedule(new EventFirer(new MyEvent()), whenToFire);
    }
    return timer;
}
```

And then let the Timer do the rest...
In fact the Timer would be the Simulator thread then. Of course internally it has it thread. However I have no idea if it's timing is acurate enough for what you need. I only used it where a second more or less didn't matter. And I think it calculates the time to sleep until next event. As such it should be as acurate as your solution.